# How can i resolve problem with loading system if i have some of this error?

Tags: system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu and everything works well, I have configured VOIP on it, and today he had some problems and when he goes to reboot, I can't restart the system and I have this error:

```
1:/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol02: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY(i.e. , without –a or –p options)
```

can anyone tell me what means this error and how I can resolve it ?

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to recovery mode ( select it in GRUB ).
2. Find option FSCK in recovery mode menu.
   OR
3. Run FSCK manually from recovery-mode root shell promt.

It's looks that your filesystem have some error, and system tells you to run FSCK for fixing it.

Comment: i read this instruction, but i don't know root password to enter in SHELL Mode, and i would't make some changes because i'm afraid to lose some configuration and files, do you know other solution to this problem, can i repair this file system with other software or commands ?

thanks

Comment: Post the output of `fsck -n` (it wont change anything, just show the problems)

Comment: you mean to read the command fsck -N in command line, whitout entering in root ? shell mode ?

Comment: Uhh, basically you can't do anything without root privilegies, sorry

Comment: i know ))) but i will try now with GParted maybe with this software i can check and resolv my problem, thanks for advices ;)

Comment: @user3472578  gparted won't work. http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password